# Имена, похожие на название сайта

Tags: обсуждение, профиль-участника, правила

На сайте есть несколько участников с именами, которые подозрительно напоминают название самого сайта. Думаю, это не очень хорошо, потому что может запутать новичка и создать впечатление, что какой-то комментарий, вопрос или ответ оставлен от лица администрации сайта, редактора или кого-то подобного.

С другой стороны, при минимальной сообразительности должно быть понятно, где сайт, а где — пользователь. На том же en.SO целая куча подобных пользователей.

Примеры:

- [На ru.SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=stackoverf)
- [На en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=stackoverf)

Точно нельзя активно и умышленно выдавать себя за сотрудника SO. В частности, невозможно добавить робм в имя пользователя. Но каких-то правил, регламентирующих вышеуказанные имена, я не нашёл (возможно, не хватает навыка понимания юридических документов на английском).

Вопросы и к сообществу, и к руководству (@Nicolas):

- Есть ли проблема с такими именами и нужно ли предлагать участникам их сменить?
- Всё-таки, есть ли документированные правила по этой части?

Что удалось найти:

- [What are the rules governing display names and avatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars)
- [Is making yourself appear (at first glance) to be a moderator acceptable behaviour?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230643/is-making-yourself-appear-at-first-glance-to-be-a-moderator-acceptable-behavio)
- [How far should we go in disallowing 'impersonation' in profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279108/how-far-should-we-go-in-disallowing-impersonation-in-profiles)

Comment: Будь проблема с такими именами юридической - все упомянутые по ссылке пользователи уже были бы переименованы, имхо.

Comment: @alexolut наверное, да. Но лучше добиться определённости, чем гадать.

Comment: Собираетесь переименоваться в NickOverflow, и не хотите столкнуться с проблемами? :)

Comment: Вот что мне действительно не нравится, так это допустимость дубликатов в именах.

Comment: @avp всё как в жизни, бывают же полные тёзки. Но паспорта (id) всё же разные. Да и аватарка своего рода идентификатор.

Comment: @alexolut, не все, что мы наблюдаем в жизни, правильно. Что тут мешает сделать имя аналогом ID (наверное, уже принятое когда-то проектное решение не проверять и т.о. упростить код)?

Comment: @avp Проблема, наверное, в том, что использование имени как аналога ID не решит проблему дубликатов имён или крайне похожих имён, например: avp и аvp. Плюс в качестве имени сейчас позволяется указывать очень многое.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, говоря об аналоге, я имел в виду лишь уникальность ID. Иными словами, надо бы при заведении (редактировании)  имени проверять его на уникальность (только и всего). А вот многого может и не надо позволять. Я бы ограничился ascii